# How to get selenium using python and chromedriver to work using headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, automation, headless

I'm trying to get selenium to run chrome in headless mode but I keep getting this error:

```
[0119/174012.114:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "A preload for 'https://www.bing.com/rp/lmu8EBCaPRMKtay8LSArGyY3mv4.br.js' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute.", source: https://www.bing.com/rb/5q/cj,nj/sCPt57pbiTV6DFHANCn0N1monu0.js?bu=DOIj8yLRBYIj5SOMI5Qj6SO4I6Ei7COMDQ (3)
[0119/174012.970:INFO:CONSOLE(73)] "BSSO Telemetry: {"result":"Error","error":"NoExtension","type":"ChromeSsoTelemetry","data":{},"traces":["BrowserSSO Initialized","Creating ChromeBrowserCore provider","Sending message for method CreateProviderAsync","Received message for method CreateProviderAsync","Error: ChromeBrowserCore error NoExtension: Extension is not installed."]}", source: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=9ea1ad79-fdb6-4f9a-8bc3-2b70f96e34c7&response_type=id_token&nonce=156143de-ffcd-48a3-977e-49b1927ca0d0&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2forgid%2fidtoken%2fnosignin&scope=openid&response_mode=form_post&msafed=0&prompt=none&state=%7b%22ig%22%3a%228CBA4BB2161B42E2AE5CE54340B61CEE%22%7d (73)
[0119/174014.718:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://www.bing.com/rp/lmu8EBCaPRMKtay8LSArGyY3mv4.br.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://www.bing.com/ (0)
```

The code throwing this error is:

```
def computer_searches():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
    driver.get("https://www.bing.com")
```

I'm fairly certain that the problem is just headless mode because if I run this without the headless mode option then it works perfectly.

Comment: I ran it as written (only removed the executable_path) without any issues

Comment: It also ran without problems for me.